# Monte Carlo estimation of this probability

Tags: density-function, monte-carlo, simulation, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let $p=P(X+Y\geq t)$ and $t\in \Bbb R$.
**Question:** Using the classic Monte Carlo method, find an estimator $p_n$ of $p$ using $F^{-1}_X$ and $F^{-1}_Y$

**Attempt:** I defined $$Z=X+Y$$ then I expressed $$p=1-P(Z \lt t)
=1-\Bbb E(\unicode{x1D7D9}_{z<t})
$$
but I didn't know where to go from here, how am I supposed to use $F^{-1}_X$ and $F^{-1}_Y$ to get the expression of the estimator?

Comment: Where you get? $P(Z \lt t)=\Bbb E(\unicode{x1D7D9}_{z<t})$

Comment: @herbsteinberg isn't the the expected value of an indicator random variable for an event is just the probability of that event?

Comment: Yes - I'm not used to term.  What is $n$ in $p_n$?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this when $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Here are the steps:

Start with $P=0$. For each $i\in\{1,...,n\}$

- follow this [well known method](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3499892/sampling-from-a-distribution-with-given-pdf/3499920#3499920) and draw two independent uniform random variables $U_i,V_i$ on $[0,1]$
- calculate $X_i=F_X^{-1}(U_i)$ and $Y_i=F_X^{-1}(V_i)$
- calculate $p_i=\mathbb 1_{\{X_i+Y_i\ge t\}}$ and add it to $P$
- when you have reached $i=n$ divide $P$ by $n$

This gives you a Monte Carlo approximation of $p=P(X+Y\ge t)$.